# How can I pass a base64 pdf to the server-side in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api, html-to-pdf

**Overall Goal**

1. Generate a pdf of the currently displayed html page;
2. ***Pass it to the server-side;***
3. Save into a specific Google Drive

Item 2 is the one I'm having trouble with!

I'm using this to try to get the converted file passed to the server-side:

**Client Side**

```
function saveToGDrive(){
var element = document.getElementById('pgBody');
var opt = {
  margin: 1,
  filename: 'myfile.pdf',
  image: {
    type: 'jpeg',
    quality: 0.98
  },
  html2canvas: {
    scale: 5
  },
  jsPDF: {
    unit: 'in',
    format: 'A4',
    orientation: 'landscape'
  }
};

const pg = html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).outputPdf().then(function(p) {
    console.log('PDF file: ' + typeof btoa(p))
    return btoa(p);
});
google.script.run.savePdf(pg)
}
```

Item 2 gives me the error: `Failed due to illegal value in property: state` and I'm taking the variable `pg` is too large to be passed as a parameter like this.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Stringified it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
const pg = html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).outputPdf().then(function(p) {
    console.log('PDF file: ' + typeof btoa(p))
    return btoa(p);
});
google.script.run.savePdf(pg)
```

#### To:

```
html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).outputPdf().then(function(p) {
  google.script.run.savePdf(btoa(p));
});
```

- When this script is run, the base64 data of `btoa(p)` is sent to the Google Apps Script side.
- When `savePdf` is the following script, the base64 data is converted to a Blob and saved as a PDF file on Google Drive.

  ```
    const savePdf = e => DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(e), MimeType.PDF).setName("samplename.pdf"));
  ```